# Separate column on a space after keyword

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe column that has a string, which may include several spaces. I want to use `separate` from `tidyr` (or something similar) on the space after the first time a keyword (i.e., `fruit_key` in the sample data) appears, so that I separate the one column into two columns.

**Sample Data**

```
df <- structure(list(fruit = c("Apple Orange Pineapple", "Plum Good Watermelon", 
"Plum Good Kiwi", "Plum Good Plum Good", "Cantaloupe Melon", "Blueberry Blackberry Cobbler", 
"Peach Pie Apple Pie")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

fruit_key <- c("Apple", "Plum Good", "Cantaloupe", "Blueberry", "Peach Pie")
```

**Expected Output**

```
                         fruit   Delicious                Tasty
1       Apple Orange Pineapple       Apple     Orange Pineapple
2         Plum Good Watermelon   Plum Good           Watermelon
3               Plum Good Kiwi   Plum Good                 Kiwi
4          Plum Good Plum Good   Plum Good            Plum Good
5             Cantaloupe Melon  Cantaloupe                Melon
6 Blueberry Blackberry Cobbler   Blueberry   Blackberry Cobbler
7          Peach Pie Apple Pie   Peach Pie            Apple Pie
```

I  can get the part after the keyword with `separate` into the correct column (i.e., `Tasty`), but cannot get the actual keyword to return for the other column (i.e., `Delicious`). I tried several altering the regular expression, but could never get the correct output.

```
library(tidyr)

separate(df, fruit,
 c("Delicious", "Tasty"),
 sep = paste(fruit_key, collapse = "|"),
 extra = "merge",
 remove = FALSE
)

#                         fruit Delicious               Tasty
#1       Apple Orange Pineapple              Orange Pineapple
#2         Plum Good Watermelon                    Watermelon
#3               Plum Good Kiwi                          Kiwi
#4          Plum Good Plum Good                     Plum Good
#5             Cantaloupe Melon                         Melon
#6 Blueberry Blackberry Cobbler            Blackberry Cobbler
#7          Peach Pie Apple Pie                     Apple Pie
```

I know that I could use `str_extract` and `str_remove` (like below), but want to use something like `separate` to do it in one function/step.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Delicious = str_extract(fruit, paste(fruit_key, collapse = "|")),
         Tasty = str_remove(fruit, paste(fruit_key, collapse = "|")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to use `separate` with `sep`, then create a regex lookaround - `"(?<=<fruit_key>) "` i.e. split at the space that succeeds the fruit_key word and as is not vectorized, `collapse` into a single string with `|` (`str_c`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   separate(fruit, into = c("Delicious", "Tasty"), 
     sep = str_c(sprintf("(?<=%s) ", fruit_key), collapse = "|"), 
         extra = "merge", remove = FALSE)
```

-output

```
                       fruit  Delicious              Tasty
1       Apple Orange Pineapple      Apple   Orange Pineapple
2         Plum Good Watermelon  Plum Good         Watermelon
3               Plum Good Kiwi  Plum Good               Kiwi
4          Plum Good Plum Good  Plum Good          Plum Good
5             Cantaloupe Melon Cantaloupe              Melon
6 Blueberry Blackberry Cobbler  Blueberry Blackberry Cobbler
7          Peach Pie Apple Pie  Peach Pie          Apple Pie
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tidy solution with `tidyr`'s function `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  extract(fruit,
          into = c("Delicious", "Tasty"),
          regex = paste0("(", paste0(fruit_key, collapse = "|"), ")\\s(.*)"),
          remove = FALSE)
                         fruit  Delicious              Tasty
1       Apple Orange Pineapple      Apple   Orange Pineapple
2         Plum Good Watermelon  Plum Good         Watermelon
3               Plum Good Kiwi  Plum Good               Kiwi
4          Plum Good Plum Good  Plum Good          Plum Good
5             Cantaloupe Melon Cantaloupe              Melon
6 Blueberry Blackberry Cobbler  Blueberry Blackberry Cobbler
7          Peach Pie Apple Pie  Peach Pie          Apple Pie
```

In `extract`'s regex argument, we collapse `fruit_key`into an alternation pattern, which we wrap into parentheses so that it is recognized as a capturing group. The second capturing group is simply whatever follows after the whitespace.

Comment: Awesome, I haven't used this one before! So, I understand that `extract` uses regular expressions to capture groups (so different than `separate`). But when would you want to use one over the other? Just trying to understand the difference a little more.

Comment: To my understanding you use `separate`when you have a clear splitting pattern 'in the middle'. Conversely, with `extract`you don't need any such clear and simple splitting point. What you do is using capturing groups, ie. `(...)`and non-capturing groups outside of `(...)`, you describe the *whole* string in an abstract way. In your case, the regex `paste0("(", paste0(fruit_key, collapse = "|"), ")\\s(.*)")` describes the strings in `fruits` exhaustively. The trick is that you put into capturing groups what you want to extract and do not put into such capturing groups what you want to drop.